# Перечисления. Метод GetValue в цикле

Tags: c#, циклы

всем привет, имеется следующий пример:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Enum.GetValues() - возвращает экземпляр System.Array, при этом каждому элементу массива 
            // будет соответствовать член указанного перечисления.

            // Помещаем в массив элементы перечисления.
            Array array = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));

            // Получаем информацию о количестве элементов в массиве.
            Console.WriteLine("Это перечисление содержит {0} членов \n", array.Length);

            // Вывод на экран всех элементов перечисления
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Имя константы: {0}, значение {0:D}", array.GetValue(i));
            }

            // Delay.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

вот само перечисление:

```
 enum EnumType
    {
        Zero,  // = 0 
        One = 1,
        one = One,
        Two = 2,
        Three, // = 3
        Four,  // = 4
        Five = 5,
        //Six,
        Seven,
        Eight = 8,
        Nine,
        Ten = 10,
        Infinite = 255
    }
```

у меня вопрос по поводу цикла

```
// Вывод на экран всех элементов перечисления
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Имя константы: {0}, значение {0:D}", array.GetValue(i));
        }
```

В переменной arrray типа Array содержится все элементы перечисления EnumType, которые представленны в виде таблицы как и любой другой массив, а метод GetValue по i-му номеру вытягивает данные о элементе массива констант записанного в переменную array.

Так вот, этот массив создается как одномерный или как двумерный - т.к константа перечисления состоит из имени и значения?

Comment: вы берете только значения, `GetValues` - откуда может взяться второе измерение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В перечисления существует только один тип значения -- собственно члены перечисления (то, что вы назвали именем). Поэтому когда вы получаете подобный массив, то это естественно одномерный массив, который содержит только значения перечисления.

Другое дело, что каждый член перечисления может быть явно приведен к числу. Но это не влияет на получаемый массив и тем более никак не связано с индексом `i` в приведенном цикле.